# Controller / Action for guest users (Does not require authentication) using Yii2-user

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I am using Yii2 (basic) and [Yii2-user](https://github.com/nkostadinov/yii2-user/) for a website with users. For most actions it's necessary to be authenticated. How could I make a controller / action accessible as a guest?

I have tried things like this in the guest's controller:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'allow' => true,
        'actions' => ['index', 'confirm', 'download-form', 'upload-form'],
    ]
],
```

And this should be enough. But nope. I suspect that it is Yii2-user module who gets in the way and always redirects me to login.

And I have added the module in the web.php configuration like this:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    ...

    'user' => [
        'class' => 'nkostadinov\user\components\User',
        'identityClass' => 'nkostadinov\user\models\User',
        'enableConfirmation' => false,
        'as firstLoginPolicy' => [ 
            'class' => 'nkostadinov\user\behaviors\FirstLoginPolicyBehavior'
        ],
    ],
],
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it as follows.

In my web.php configuration I had this:

```
'modules' => [
...
],
'as access' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),//AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'request', 'change-password'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?']
        ],
        [
            //'actions' => ['logout', 'index'], // add all actions to take guest to login page
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],        
   ],
],
'params' => [ ... ]
```

So, I have added this new rule to grant guest users access to all actions of this controller:

```
[
    'controllers' => ['mymodule/my-controller'],    
    'allow' => true,    
],
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use mdmsoft/yii2-admin for authentication